# Isometric 3d Plot

Tags: graphics3d

I was wondering if its possible to make the following type of plot in Mathematica:

I would like to take a 3D object, such as an ellipsoid, and cut out a wedge.  I know this can be done using SphericalPlot3D and only plotting through an azimuthal angle phi.  But here's the tricky part.  Usually, whats left is a hollow shell, but I want to make it seem as if its a solid object with the inside colored according to some function.  So what you would see when you cut out the wedge is a flat surface colored according to some function.

If this is not possible with Mathematica, can anyone recommend a program where this may be done?

Comment: It can be done using [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot3D.html).

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: @RahulNarain: I agree, the title is misleading.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what is misleading about the title. I want to make an isometric object with a plot inside of a cutout of it.  I think the title us summarizes the question quite well.

Comment: An "isometric" 3D drawing usually refers to [a parallel projection with all three axes at 120º](http://www3.ul.ie/~rynnet/keanea/isometri.htm), as seen in [old video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Diabloscreen.jpg). Also, the title indicates nothing about cutting a wedge from a solid object and putting a plot inside the cut-out part.

Comment: Well yes, the details are in the body, as it should be. Otherwise the title would be too long.   And yes I was looking to make an isometric plot, just as the title says.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way using `SphericalPlot3D`.

The segment of the surface is closed by two polygons that are formed from vertices of the boundary of the surface plot.  You have to repeat the `PlotStyle` explicitly for the `Polygon`s.  A similar approach works for `ParametricPlot3D`, too, provided the wedge of the surface is cut by planes (i.e. can be represented by planar polygons).

The idea is to sow the sample `theta`, `phi` values, recover them, and extract the boundaries.  These can be remapped onto the surface and become the vertices of the polygons that form the angle of the wedge.  The order of the vertices of the first polygon is reversed to get the right orientation (in case `FaceForm` is used, for example).

```
sph[r_, theta_, phi_] := r {Sin[theta] Cos[phi], Sin[theta] Sin[phi], Cos[theta]};

wedge = With[{r = 1 + Sin[5 phi]/5},
 Module[{plot, pts},
  {plot, {pts}} = Reap @ SphericalPlot3D[r, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0.5, 1.8}, 
       Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Yellow, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{theta, phi}]];
  Show[
   plot,
   Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon[
      Apply[Function @@ {{theta, phi}, sph[r, theta, phi]},
       {Reverse @ Sort @ Cases[pts, {_, Min[Last /@ pts]}], 
        Sort @ Cases[pts, {_, Max[Last /@ pts]}]},
       {2}]
      ]}]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get an [isometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) of the graphics, you can play with `ViewMatrix`.  The key is to rotate a vector of the form $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ to $(0,0,1)$ and project onto the first two coordinates.  Translating and scaling will depend on the particular graphics, but perhaps the example below is sufficiently generalizable.

```
Show[wedge, 
 ViewMatrix ->
  {TransformationMatrix[
     RescalingTransform[
       1.02 EuclideanDistance @@ Transpose[PlotRange /.
            AbsoluteOptions[wedge, PlotRange]] {{-1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}] .
     RotationTransform[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}] .
     TranslationTransform[-Mean /@ (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[wedge, PlotRange])]
    ],
   IdentityMatrix[4]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible approach for the filled inside of a spherical wedge. The rest of the work consists in choosing the elliptical shape with the desired eccentricities, and possibly drawing a solid shell on top of it:

```
RegionPlot3D[(EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, {0, 0, 0}] < 1 && 
   0 < ArcTan[x, y] < Pi/4), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: wegde]

To make the plot look isometric, just choose the `ViewPoint` far away, e.g., add `ViewPoint -> {0, 1, 1000}` to the options of `RegionPlot3D`.